# Perl string sub

Tags: perl

I want to replace something with a path like `C:\foo`, so I:

```
s/hello/c:\foo
```

But that is invalid.
Do I need to escape some chars?

Comment: When I read the title of this question ("Perl string sub"), I thought this was going to be a question about the dynamic invocation of *subroutines* by symbol table lookup. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems that I can see.

Your first problem is that your `s///` replacement is not terminated:

```
s/hello/c:\foo   # fatal syntax error:  "Substitution replacement not terminated"
s/hello/c:\foo/  # syntactically okay
s!hello!c:\foo!  # also okay, and more readable with backslashes (IMHO)
```

Your second problem, the one you asked about, is that the `\f` is taken as a *form feed escape sequence* (ASCII 0x0C), just as it would be in double quotes, which is not what you want.

You may either escape the backslash, or let variable interpolation "hide" the problem:

```
s!hello!c:\\foo!            # This will do what you want.  Note double backslash.

my $replacement = 'c:\foo'  # N.B.:  Using single quotes here, not double quotes
s!hello!$replacement!;      # This also works
```

Take a look at the treatment of *Quote and Quote-like Operators* in [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're asking, then this might be something like what you're after:

```
$path = "hello/there";
$path =~ s/hello/c:\\foo/;
print "$path\n";
```

To answer your question, yes you do need to double the backslash because `\f` is an escape sequence for "form feed" in a Perl string.

Comment: The last sentence is wrong, in fact `\f` is a valid escape sequence for *form feed*.

Comment: True, fixed. Form feed is not one I would use often!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not escaping special characters:

```
s/hello/c:\\foo/;
```

would solve your problem.  `\` is a special character so you need to escape it.  `{}[]()^$.|*+?\` are meta (special) characterss which you need to escape.

Additional reference: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html